# Can I reload single changed Erlang module without stopping running application?

Tags: erlang

I have Erlang application which takes long time to start and even more to fully recompile. I make little changes which I'd like to test as fast as possible. I want to compile and load my changes without stopping the application. How to do it from Erlang console which I get to after starting the application? My source code is located in `./src` directory and beam files are compiled to `./ebin` directory and I want to do the same to the changed file.
My application is started with

```sh
erl -pa ebin deps/*/ebin
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it by:

1. Loading the new version of the module, e.g. `c(module_name)`
2. Making a fully qualified call to a function in the new module.  "Fully qualified" means:

   ```
    module_name:function_name()
   ```

   The module is only updated in the process where the fully qualified function call is made.

Here is an example:

a.erl:

```
-module(a).
-compile(export_all).

start() -> 
    %% Long startup time:
    timer:sleep(1000), 

    spawn(fun() -> loop() end).

loop() ->
    receive
        {a, Msg} -> 
            show1(Msg),
            loop();
        {b, Msg} -> 
            show2(Msg),
            loop();
        update_code -> a:loop()
    end.

show1(Arg) ->
    %%io:format("Hello ~w!~n", [Arg]).  %original code
    io:format("XXX ~w!~n", [Arg]).  %new code

show2(Arg) ->
    %%io:format("Goodbye ~w!~n", [Arg]).  %original code      
    io:format("YYY ~w!~n", [Arg]).  %new code
```

In the shell:

```
1> c(a).           
a.erl:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
{ok,a}

2> Pid = a:start().
<0.72.0>

3> a:show1(jane).  %%Executed by shell process.
Hello jane!
ok

4> Pid ! {a, jane}. %% show1/1 executed in spawned process.
Hello jane!
{a,jane}

5> c(a).           
a.erl:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
{ok,a}

6> a:show1(jane).  %%Module updated in shell process.
XXX jane!
ok

7> Pid ! {a, jane}.
Hello jane!     <---- STILL EXECUTING OLD MODULE
{a,jane}

8> Pid ! update_code.  %% Make fully qualified function call in spawned process.
update_code

9> Pid ! {a, jane}.  %% The whole module has been replaced by new code.
XXX jane!
{a,jane}

10> Pid ! {b, jane}.   
YYY jane!
{b,jane}

11>
```

Comment: Cool, it mostly works with exception of the case when I create new module in src directory. When I try to c(new_mod). in console, I get {error,non_existing}. I also tried l(new_mod). It gives me {error,nofile}. Can we load new module to the working application?

Comment: @AndreyKo, With `c()`, you can use a relative path (or an absolute path) enclosed in quotes to compile and load a module in another directory.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! c("src/new_mod.erl"). did the trick. I didn't know that c function takes not only atoms as modules names but module path as well. I've also noticed that after this there did not appear any new_mod.beam file. Neither in root directory nor in ebin or src, nowhere. It's interesting. I thought that it would compile beam file for me.

Comment: @AndreyKo, Look in the current directory for the .beam file.

Comment: @AndreyKo, You can specify the output directory like this:  `c("src/new_mod.erl", {outdir, ["./ebin"]})`

Comment: I found new_mod.beam in the current directory, I had checked in the currently working directory before and apparently my eyes were too tired to notice it, I'm sorry for the misleading message. c("src/new_mod.erl", {output, ["./ebin"]}) is what I needed! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Just to add to the other answers:

When you do a release, you may have two versions of your application and you may want to upgrade. Say, you first have `lib/foo-1.0.0/ebin/foo_app.beam` loaded. Then you install `foo-2.0.0` via your preferred method, I use `target_system:install("foo", "/tmp/erl-target")`. Now I have `/tmp/erl-target/lib/foo-2.0.0/`.

I use `code:which(foo_app)` to see which one is loaded. To load it, in this case I would first start the Eshell as such:

```sh
$ /tmp/erl-target/bin/erl -boot /tmp/erl-target/releases/1/start
```

Afterwards I type:

```erlang
1> application:ensure_all_started(foo).
{ok,[...,foo]}
```

To see which one is currently loaded, you type (in the same Eshell):

```erlang
2> code:which(foo_app).                                  
"/tmp/erl-target/lib/foo-1.0.0/ebin/foo_app.beam"
```

You will need the `foo.appup` file in `/tmp/erl-target/lib/foo-2.0.0/ebin/` with the following contents:

```erlang
{"2.0.0",
 [{"1.0.0",[{load_module,foo_app}]}],
 [{"1.0.0",[{load_module,foo_app}]}]}.
```

To upgrade, you type:

```erlang
3> release_handler:upgrade_app(foo, 'lib/foo-2.0.0').
{ok,[]}
```

If everything was successful, you will see the following:

```
4> code:which(foo_app).                                  
"/tmp/erl-target/lib/foo-2.0.0/ebin/foo_app.beam"
```

If I added a new function in `foo-2.0.0` which I exported, it will become available, for example.

If you want to downgrade back to the previous version, you will have to have a similar `foo.appup` file in `/tmp/erl-target/lib/foo-1.0.0/ebin/`, but with the version numbers swapped.

---

Please correct me if I am wrong, I am new to Erlang. I did test it myself and it worked for me. This is just to upgrade your application within a release, this is not upgrading the release itself.

If something is unclear, let me know. I am still trying to work this out myself. :)

Answer (score 2):

Compile the module as you usually do, and then type this into the erlang shell:

```
l(my_module).
```

This will load code from the new `my_module.beam` file and replace the `my_module` module.

The old version might not go away completely - see [the section on Code Reloading](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/code_loading.html#code-replacement) in the Erlang reference manual for details.

Comment: When I create new module after I started application and try to compile it in already opened erlang console like c(new_mod). I get error {error,non_existing}. I also tried l(new_mod). It gives me {error,nofile}.